# How to get rid of certain parts of a string input?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I just started my first programming class and I am trying to write a program that uses JOption dialogue boxes and can't seem to figure out how to create the right output. I am trying to have the user enter a URL into the dialogue input box, and have an output dialogue box display just the website name without the www. or the .com portion.  Thanks in advance!

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   String input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
           "Please enter website URL");
   String.output=JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
           )
```

Comment: So you need to test if the `String` `contains` `www` and/or `.com` (or `.org` or some other domain), then get a `substring` between the first `.` and next `.`

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in java called replace() that would be perfect for this scenario.

For learning knowledge, the method looks like this(it is built in) :

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

But in order to call it, you can put in your string .  replace of course with the parameters.

```
input.replace("www" , "") //Makes the www blank
```

I recommend putting these into switch/if statements.

```
if (input.contains ("www") {
input.replace("www" , "") //Makes the www blank
}
```

Now, if you also want to get rid of .com if it exists, then:

```
if(input.contains(".com"){
input.replace(".com", "")
}
```

Thats it. First, check if the user entered the stuff you don't want using .contains, and if they did remove it using .replace.

```
~{Rich}
```